# How can I go to a new page from within javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a link like this:

```
<a href="www.example.com">
```

I would like to simulate the clicking of this link within javascript with a function that is called with the left arrow but I am not sure how to do it.

Now I have this:

```
$(window).keypress(function (e)
{
   if (e.keyCode == 37)
   {
    //  position 1
   }

});
```

But I am not sure how to change the page to the link "www.example.com" from within javascript at position 1. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen, I present to you the reason www.example.com is used in these sorts of examples.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use the following to perform a redirect:

```
window.location.href = 'www.example.com';
```

Answer (score 2):

You could set [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to the url you want the page to load, like:

```
window.location = "www.example.com"
```